# mysql-workbench does not see database changes made by other clients unless restarting connection

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I use mysql-workbench in order to query my database tables.
Also I use a Java application (with `mysql-connector-java`) in order to make changes to my database.

Every time the java app modifies the database I am unable to see the changes using mysql-workbench. The query return no results.

Only after I restart the MySQL Connection and run the query again, I am able to see the changes.

I use `mysql-workbench version 6.3.8`, `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.16`, `mysql-connector-java 5.1.38` and my OS is `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`.

From the Java application I use this code in order to modify the database state:

```
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
.....
session.save(myObject);
transaction.commit();
```

Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have no auto commit enabled, hence changes are not visible to any other client until you explicitly called commit. You can test this also with the command line mysql client and it will give you the same result. A similar question has been asked a few days ago: [Mysql Workbench is not reading records inserted through JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40374473/mysql-workbench-is-not-reading-records-inserted-through-jdbc)

Comment: You have directed me to the right path. I use hibernate and I commit my transaction. However, I did not flush my session. Inserting `session.flush()` before the `transaction.commit()` fixes my issue. Now I can immediately see the query results in mysql-workbench

Comment: It seems like the commit alone is not enough to cause the persistence context to be synched with the database. I need to call flush explicitly in order to achieve that...